# mix-blend-mode doesn't work over a canvas

Tags: css, svg, canvas, mix-blend-mode

I have content rendered in a canvas, and I want to place an SVG on top.

Problem:

- `mix-blend-mode` works (Chromium and Edge) with an empty canvas, but stops working if I draw something on the canvas
- Neither version works in Firefox

Below is a minimal example of how it looks with and without the canvas.

How can I make this work with a canvas in a way that's cross-browser compatible?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,128)';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.font = '48px serif';
ctx.strokeText('Hello world', 0, 48);
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

path {
  stroke: yellow;
  stroke-width: 5em;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

div.box svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="300px" height="300px" ></canvas>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sodales mauris nunc, id pretium nunc laoreet eget. Etiam tempus massa id vulputate mattis. Donec nisl felis, sodales at mi vel, tincidunt sodales dui. Aliquam eu massa finibus, malesuada orci eget, aliquam risus. Pellentesque nec sodales nisi. Pellentesque mollis, odio non congue imperdiet, ipsum mi eleifend lorem, nec placerat mi nisl hendrerit arcu. Nullam vehicula, ligula non vestibulum faucibus, turpis quam dapibus tellus, ut malesuada erat leo vitae arcu. Cras in mi ut ante suscipit feugiat. Suspendisse ut mollis arcu, at sollicitudin risus. Sed non tincidunt dui, quis tempus mauris. Nulla accumsan efficitur sem vel porta. Sed id nulla odio. Aenean vitae placerat nibh, vel congue orci.
    Quisque pellentesque molestie mi, quis tempus ligula convallis faucibus. Nunc at ipsum hendrerit, volutpat lectus euismod, elementum justo. Duis lacinia nibh hendrerit odio mollis, id interdum nisl pulvinar. Pellentesque vehicula tellus id orci porta, vel tincidunt massa auctor. In sollicitudin condimentum auctor. Nunc odio felis, maximus volutpat ligula ut, euismod efficitur velit. Praesent a lectus eleifend, accumsan erat vitae, malesuada nulla. Etiam tincidunt aliquet elit sed volutpat. Integer vel nulla quis dui aliquam feugiat sed nec orci. Praesent id ex rhoncus, egestas lectus eget, auctor urna. Phasellus tristique efficitur mauris, sit amet fringilla nunc pellentesque at. Vestibulum aliquam mi quis aliquam condimentum. Praesent cursus nisl congue, efficitur tellus eu, cursus sapien. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin est nunc, tincidunt quis lacus non, lacinia tristique dui.
  </div>
  <div>
    <svg width="1px" height="1px">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 500 500" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

path {
  stroke: yellow;
  stroke-width: 5em;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

div.box svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="300px" height="300px" ></canvas>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sodales mauris nunc, id pretium nunc laoreet eget. Etiam tempus massa id vulputate mattis. Donec nisl felis, sodales at mi vel, tincidunt sodales dui. Aliquam eu massa finibus, malesuada orci eget, aliquam risus. Pellentesque nec sodales nisi. Pellentesque mollis, odio non congue imperdiet, ipsum mi eleifend lorem, nec placerat mi nisl hendrerit arcu. Nullam vehicula, ligula non vestibulum faucibus, turpis quam dapibus tellus, ut malesuada erat leo vitae arcu. Cras in mi ut ante suscipit feugiat. Suspendisse ut mollis arcu, at sollicitudin risus. Sed non tincidunt dui, quis tempus mauris. Nulla accumsan efficitur sem vel porta. Sed id nulla odio. Aenean vitae placerat nibh, vel congue orci.
    Quisque pellentesque molestie mi, quis tempus ligula convallis faucibus. Nunc at ipsum hendrerit, volutpat lectus euismod, elementum justo. Duis lacinia nibh hendrerit odio mollis, id interdum nisl pulvinar. Pellentesque vehicula tellus id orci porta, vel tincidunt massa auctor. In sollicitudin condimentum auctor. Nunc odio felis, maximus volutpat ligula ut, euismod efficitur velit. Praesent a lectus eleifend, accumsan erat vitae, malesuada nulla. Etiam tincidunt aliquet elit sed volutpat. Integer vel nulla quis dui aliquam feugiat sed nec orci. Praesent id ex rhoncus, egestas lectus eget, auctor urna. Phasellus tristique efficitur mauris, sit amet fringilla nunc pellentesque at. Vestibulum aliquam mi quis aliquam condimentum. Praesent cursus nisl congue, efficitur tellus eu, cursus sapien. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin est nunc, tincidunt quis lacus non, lacinia tristique dui.
  </div>
  <div>
    <svg width="1px" height="1px">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 500 500" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a still mockup of what you wish to achieve? Note that setting the `mix-blend-mode` rule on the `<svg>`'s grandparent `<div>` will make FF work as Chrome. https://jsfiddle.net/w7Lb5fyx/

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I needed. Do you know why it only works on the parent and not on the `<svg>` or the `<path>`?

Comment: I don't, and I don't want to search for it, sorry. Last time I checked the specs in this area (I admit it was a long time ago), it was a real mess, and no two implementers would read it the same way... Add to this that browsers don't stop creating bugs by trying to improve their layer renderers without properly testing every edge cases and you may have two completely different rendering of the same page on the same browser depending only on if the user moved their mouse over it or not... I personally stick to things I can control, i.e for this kind of rendering, I only trust a <canvas>.

Comment: However I'm following this Q/A in the hope someone has more time and will than I have to dig things out.